# Exeption while listing active serial ports using pyserial

Tags: python, serial-port, pyserial, iterable

i'm a new python learner. 
i'm trying to list my active serial ports with this simple code

```
import serial.tools.list_ports as port_list
ports = list(port_list.main())
for p in ports:

    print (p)
```

this is the reasult

```
C:\Python27\python.exe C:/Users/tc34669/PycharmProjects/untitled/open_serial_port.py
COM1                
COM3                
2 ports found
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/tc34669/PycharmProjects/untitled/open_serial_port.py", line 2, in <module>
ports = list(port_list.main())
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

Someone here knows how can i list these ports without this TypeError ?

thanks

Comment: As can be seen in the output you provided (and it is also obvious from the name of the function that for some reason you decided to rename) `list_ports` just lists (=prints) the ports and returns `None`. Read the docs and search for a function that actually returns a port list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [`documentation of pySerial`](http://pyserial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tools.html) `main()` isn't actually a documented function you can use to get the info of all the ports. Try using the `comports()` function instead :

```
from serial.tools import list_ports
for p in list_ports.comports():
    print(p)
```

Comment: I've tried this function already but the output i got was too long (e.g -  COM1 - Communications Port (COM1)). I want to convert these ports into variables that each one contains only the port number (e.g COM1). This is the reason why i tried with the 'main' function, the output is what i need but this typeerror blocks me. If you know about a diffrent way it will be great.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to print only the port numbers, (e.g COM1), try using the comport objects 'device' property:

```
from serial.tools import list_ports
for p in list_ports.comports():
    print(p.device)
```